# Name List based on another column (unique and repeated names)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula

I have a column where names of soccer teams are recorded, sometimes those names are repeated and sometimes not.

Example:

```
Vasco da Gama
Flamengo
Flamengo
Goiás
Internacional
Vasco da Gama
```

I would like to have another column where these names are recorded but without repetitions, so that I can analyze how many teams I have in total.

Like this:

```
Vasco da Gama
Flamengo
Goiás
Internacional
```

The names are in Column A.

I already tried to use the `FILTER` function, but could not remove the repeated names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNIQUE` function is what you need:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect! Stack asked to wait 7 minutes before it could activate its response with the positive mark. As soon as I can, I'll leave it checked. Thanks!